# Список файлов в вектор

Tags: c++, boost

Используя библиотеку boost 1.63, я пытался реализовать вывод список файлов в директории в вектор с типом string. В целевой папке находится три файла.

```
std::vector<std::string> Stuff::fpathvector(const char* paths)

{
    std::vector<std::string> vector;
    vector.reserve(fnumber(paths)); // Выхлопом метода является int, количество файлов. Сам paths = "./resources/map"

    for(directory_iterator rdib(paths), rdie; rdib != rdie; ++rdib)
    {
        vector.push_back(rdib->path().filename().string());
    }
    for(auto const& filename : vector)
    {
        std::cout << filename << '\n';
    }

    return vector;
}
```

Однако в вектор ничего не вносится, а при попытке обратиться к первому элементу вектора, я получаю просто символ. Даже через cout не выводится имя файла. Подозреваю что я совершил где-то ошибку, но не - не понимаю. Компилятор не предупреждает и ошибок не выдаёт.

```
auto fpathvector("./resources/map");
cout << fpathvector[0];
```

Comment: А что означают ваши последние строки?... Как я понимаю, вы должны использовать примерно так - `auto f = Stuff::fpathvector(path); cout << f[0];` (если `Stuff::fpathvector` - `static`).

Comment: @Harry я пытался вывести любой из элементов вектора, чтобы проверить его работоспособность. И этот метод не является "static".

Забавно, сейчас всё сработало и вывелось как следует. Сможете в ответе объяснить по какой причине моя конструкция не работала? Мне нужно было присвоить переменной значение метода, который возвращает вектор, и работать уже с переменной?

Comment: Просто первая строка - это определение строки `const char * fpathvector` со значением "./resources/map", а второе - вывод первого символа этой строки (точки). Что до `static` - я же не знаю, что у вас `Stuff` - я думал, имя класса, а вызов вне его...

Comment: @Harry по примерам я читал, что надо делить реализацию и интерфейсы. Интерфейсы пихать в h файлы, и оставлять там только объявления функций и переменных класса. А саму реализацию пихать в cpp. Stuff - имя класса, а fpathvector - метод этого класса.

Comment: Но в вашей функции нигде не работает сам объект класса, для которого вызывается функция. Так? Тогда **почему** она должна быть членом класса? Почему не свободной функцией? В крайнем случае - статической функцией класса? Вам же нужно, чтобы ее вызвать, создавать объект :(